# Time counter in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

I would like to implement a counter that displays running time. The use case should look like this: With a button click the start time gets determined. In a text field the increasing running time should be displayed. So after one second 1, after two seconds 2, and so on. When i click another button the time counter stops and the current number of seconds freezes.

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
String elapsedSeconds = Long.toString(elapsedTime / 1000);
this.textField.setValue(elapsedSeconds);
```

How do i implement that very second the corresponding amount of seconds will be shown in the text field. Do i have to refresh the text field every second? If that's the case, how do i do it?

Edit:

```
@Push
public class View {

    private final UI ui = this.getUI();
    private final long startTime;
    public View(final long startTime) {
        super();
        this.initUI();
        this.startTime = startTime;
        final Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new LiveTime(), 0, 1000);
        }

    private class LiveTime extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            final long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - View.this.startTime;
            final String elapsedSeconds = Long.toString(elapsedTime / 1000);
            View.this.ui.access(() -> View.this.textField.setValue(elapsedSeconds));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need three things.

1. A task or a thread that does the updating.

Here's one example on how to do a task: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-create-a-thread-which-runs-every-one-minute-in-Java. This example uses 10 min interval but you can change it to 1 second.

2. `ui.access()`

If you update the UI via a second thread, then you need to update it within a `ui.access()` call, to avoid data corruption or deadlocks.

```
ui.access(() -> textField.setValue(elapsedSeconds));
```

You can read more here: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-push-access.html

3. You need to add `@Push` to your view.

Vaadin is by default a framework which every update starts with an browser interaction, which does a server roundtrip, and then sends instructions back to browser telling how the UI should be updated. With a separate thread, the request to update does not originate from the browser. but the server, so there is not an open browser request to respond to. Therefore, none of the UI updates will end up in the browser before the user clicks on something. When you add the annotation `@Push` to your view, it instructs the browser to open a request to the server immediately, which is held open until there is new data to render in the browser. The moment that data comes, it is pushed to the browser.

More info here: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-push-configuration.html

---

**Update 2023:** In case you receive an error: "could not start Tomcat server", @Push must be placed at the entry point of the Spring Boot application, so duplex connection can start for the whole Spring App. In most Vaadin cases, it's the `Application.java` class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication()
@Theme(value = "mytodo")
@NpmPackage(value = "line-awesome", version = "1.3.0")
@Push(PushMode.AUTOMATIC) // <-------------------
public class Application implements AppShellConfigurator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

[Kudos to this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68063468/8555937)

Comment: Thank you! So in the view where the text field is located that i want to update every second, I need to add the Push annonation. In the same class I have to add `Timer timer = new Timer(); timer.schedule(new LiveTime(startTime), 0, 1000);` What do i have define in the new LiveTime Class, especially in the constructor and the run method?

Comment: The LiveTime should extend TimerTask and only have the run method. No constructor needed. The run method should define what should happen every second. In your case it sounds like you want to calculate the time and update the text field within an access call.

Roughly:
```java 
class Hello extends TimerTask {
  public void run() {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    String elapsedSeconds = Long.toString(elapsedTime / 1000);
    this.ui.access(() -> this.textField.setValue(elapsedSeconds));
  } 
} 
```

Comment: But the startTime gets defined in another class and it should get passed to the LiveTime class. Also i can't do `this.ui` in the LiveTime Class because there is no ui for the LiveTime class. I need to access the ui of the view, where the textfield is in.

Comment: Let it be an inner class as the example showed. Then you can call the fields of the outer class, including the UI and text field.

Comment: All right...now there is the error TImerThread.run() line: not availabe. I added the  new code to my post

Comment: You might have to have a `@Override` above the run method declaration. And I guess you want a TimerTask and not TimerThread. This starts to be standard Java help at this point. I suggest you read up on generic timed threads in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified answer based on @Jens Jansson and what worked for me:

In the Vaadin application:

```java
@Push(PushMode.AUTOMATIC)
public class VaadinApplication implements AppShellConfigurator {
.
.
}
```

In the view:

```java
ui = UI.getCurrent();
```

In the thread:

```java
 ui.access(()->{
   // ui updates ..
 });

 ui.push();
```