# How to use Vaadin FLOW server-push with Spring Boot

Tags: vaadin, server-push

When I use the @Push annotation on a view I get the following exception (JDK 16, Vaadin 19.0.7, Spring boot 2.4.7):

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:763) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1318) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at net.cbsolution.chameleon.ChameleonApplication.main(ChameleonApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:199) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:159) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:187) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

What shall I do to use server push with Spring boot? Can anybody point a working example?

Here is the complete log:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v2.4.7-SNAPSHOT)

2021-06-20 18:59:24.644  INFO 33309 --- [  restartedMain] n.c.chameleon.ChameleonApplication       : Starting ChameleonApplication using Java 16 on franco-HP-ZBook-15-G5 with PID 33309 (/home/franco/projects/chameleon/target/classes started by franco in /home/franco/projects/chameleon)
2021-06-20 18:59:24.646  INFO 33309 --- [  restartedMain] n.c.chameleon.ChameleonApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-06-20 18:59:24.672  INFO 33309 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in /home/franco/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/license-checker/1.2.0/license-checker-1.2.0.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/home/franco/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/license-checker/1.2.0/gwt-elemental-2.8.2.vaadin2.jar,file:/home/franco/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/license-checker/1.2.0/oshi-core-5.5.0.jar,file:/home/franco/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/license-checker/1.2.0/jna-5.7.0.jar,file:/home/franco/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/license-checker/1.2.0/jna-platform-5.7.0.jar,file:/home/franco/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/license-checker/1.2.0/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar
2021-06-20 18:59:24.672  INFO 33309 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in /home/franco/.m2/repository/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc8/19.8.0.0/ojdbc8-19.8.0.0.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/home/franco/.m2/repository/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc8/19.8.0.0/oraclepki.jar
2021-06-20 18:59:24.672  INFO 33309 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in /home/franco/.m2/repository/com/cronutils/cron-utils/9.1.5/cron-utils-9.1.5.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/home/franco/.m2/repository/com/cronutils/cron-utils/9.1.5/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar,file:/home/franco/.m2/repository/com/cronutils/cron-utils/9.1.5/javax.el-3.0.0.jar
2021-06-20 18:59:24.672  INFO 33309 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2021-06-20 18:59:24.672  INFO 33309 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2021-06-20 18:59:25.095  INFO 33309 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-06-20 18:59:25.130  INFO 33309 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 32 ms. Found 6 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-06-20 18:59:25.471  INFO 33309 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-06-20 18:59:25.475  INFO 33309 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-06-20 18:59:25.475  INFO 33309 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.46]
2021-06-20 18:59:25.525  INFO 33309 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-06-20 18:59:25.525  INFO 33309 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 853 ms
2021-06-20 18:59:25.574  INFO 33309 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-06-20 18:59:25.734  INFO 33309 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-06-20 18:59:25.737  INFO 33309 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/chameleon'
2021-06-20 18:59:25.841  INFO 33309 --- [  restartedMain] c.v.f.s.VaadinServletContextInitializer  : Search for VaadinAppShell took 17 ms
2021-06-20 18:59:25.843  INFO 33309 --- [  restartedMain] c.v.f.s.s.VaadinAppShellInitializer      : Using net.cbsolution.chameleon.MyAppShellConfigurator class for configuring `index.html` response
2021-06-20 18:59:25.848 ERROR 33309 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener]

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$VaadinAppShellContextListener
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$FailFastServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:192) ~[vaadin-spring-16.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.lambda$contextInitialized$0(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:209) ~[vaadin-spring-16.0.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:209) ~[vaadin-spring-16.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4714) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5172) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:829) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:199) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:159) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:763) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1318) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at net.cbsolution.chameleon.ChameleonApplication.main(ChameleonApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: com.vaadin.flow.server.InvalidApplicationConfigurationException: 

Found app shell configuration annotations in non `AppShellConfigurator` classes.
Please create a custom class implementing `AppShellConfigurator` and move the following annotations to it:
    - @Push from net.cbsolution.chameleon.ui.views.AlertView

    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.VaadinAppShellInitializer.init(VaadinAppShellInitializer.java:157) ~[flow-server-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.VaadinAppShellInitializer.init(VaadinAppShellInitializer.java:94) ~[flow-server-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$VaadinAppShellContextListener.failFastContextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:550) ~[vaadin-spring-16.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$FailFastServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:188) ~[vaadin-spring-16.0.1.jar:na]
    ... 47 common frames omitted

2021-06-20 18:59:25.848 ERROR 33309 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2021-06-20 18:59:25.849 ERROR 33309 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2021-06-20 18:59:25.852  WARN 33309 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@16/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@16/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
 java.base@16/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1661)
 java.base@16/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
 java.base@16/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
 java.base@16/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1056)
 java.base@16/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1116)
 java.base@16/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
 java.base@16/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
2021-06-20 18:59:25.853  WARN 33309 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 connection adder] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@16/java.lang.String.equals(String.java:1027)
 java.base@16/sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.nameOf(CipherSuite.java:898)
 java.base@16/sun.security.ssl.SSLAlgorithmDecomposer.decompose(SSLAlgorithmDecomposer.java:262)
 java.base@16/sun.security.util.AbstractAlgorithmConstraints.checkAlgorithm(AbstractAlgorithmConstraints.java:99)
 java.base@16/sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.permits(DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.java:140)
 java.base@16/sun.security.ssl.SSLAlgorithmConstraints.permits(SSLAlgorithmConstraints.java:164)
 java.base@16/sun.security.ssl.SSLAlgorithmConstraints.permits(SSLAlgorithmConstraints.java:154)
 java.base@16/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.isActivatable(HandshakeContext.java:550)
 java.base@16/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.getActiveCipherSuites(HandshakeContext.java:339)
 java.base@16/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.<init>(HandshakeContext.java:185)
 java.base@16/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.<init>(ClientHandshakeContext.java:98)
 java.base@16/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:238)
 java.base@16/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:434)
 java.base@16/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:412)
 app//org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:41)
 app//org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:534)
 app//org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:149)
 app//org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
 app//org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
 app//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
 app//org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
 app//org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
 app//com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
 app//com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
 app//com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
 app//com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
 app//com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71)
 app//com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:725)
 app//com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:711)
 java.base@16/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
 java.base@16/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
 java.base@16/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
 java.base@16/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
2021-06-20 18:59:25.870  INFO 33309 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-06-20 18:59:25.872  WARN 33309 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2021-06-20 18:59:25.873  INFO 33309 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-06-20 18:59:25.878  INFO 33309 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2021-06-20 18:59:25.885  INFO 33309 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-06-20 18:59:25.895 ERROR 33309 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:763) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1318) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at net.cbsolution.chameleon.ChameleonApplication.main(ChameleonApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:199) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:159) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:187) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.4.7-20210610.075414-42.jar:2.4.7-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 19 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

And here is **MyAppShellConfigurator**:

```
package net.cbsolution.chameleon;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.page.AppShellConfigurator;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.page.Push;

@Push
public class MyAppShellConfigurator implements AppShellConfigurator {
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a stack trace before that one in your logs?

Comment: Sorry, I complemented with the full log.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must add annotation for the "whole" application (which `@Push`
is) to your central configuration place (which is the class implementing
`AppShellConfigurator`).  As the error states:

> ```
> Found app shell configuration annotations in non `AppShellConfigurator` classes.
> Please create a custom class implementing `AppShellConfigurator` and move the following annotations to it:
>   - @Push from net.cbsolution.chameleon.ui.views.AlertView
> ```

Remove `@Push` from `net.cbsolution.chameleon.ui.views.AlertView` (as
it's already set on your `MyAppShellConfigurator` as seen in your code paste).

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm. From the documentation (https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-push-access) I got the impression that the @push annotation should be used on all views that could be target of push.

Comment: By the way I see the same class (MyAppShellConfigurator) can receive other annotations, I was able to change the themes of all views adding @Theme(themeClass = Lumo.class, variant = Lumo.DARK), just great!

Comment: @FrancoG the `AppShellConfigurator` is only available since Vaadin 15+, while the documentation you linked is for Vaadin 14. In V14 the `@Push` annotation was supposed to be in the root layout or view classes. For using newer Vaadin versions, the docs you want are under /latest - https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/overview or select the version top-left-ish on the page.

Comment: Thanks again. I think that my issue is a common one. Vaadin is moving fast (in the right direction) but searching the documentation is hard because Google privileges old content (more read and back-links). The same happens with Vaadin search buttons of the provided link. Maybe if one day you could do something like "The Vaadin book", but constantly pointing to updated documentation would be really great.

Comment: Correct, can't agree more. Thanks to all for having this conversation! Saved heaps of time for me. Got it to work in 10mins because of you guys.